# Linux bulk mtime

Tags: python, linux, performance, system-calls, stat

When handling large amounts of data, minimizing the number of database requests and doing bulk operations instead helps a lot in terms of performance.

**Question**: is it possible to retrieve the mtimes of 10,000 files at once/in bulk on Linux?

I hope to minimize system calls.

Couldn't find something here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html

PS: currently, I retrieve those filenames using python:os.walk.

Comment: I don't think bulk mtime requests are possible, but retrieving the mtimes of 10,000 files is hardly the slowest operation. Have you tried profiling your code and finding other slow parts? Perhaps it would be worth to optimize those...

Comment: If that's a no and you have some sources/references, you can make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Guess why referred to db queries? ;-) Already optimized. I also found that system-calls are 20-100x slower than function calls: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311165/why-isnt-there-generic-batching-syscall-in-linux-bsd

Comment: Other slow parts referred to anything else, db and syscalls are not the only things that can make a program slow. If you do some O(n^2) operation with data then your program will be slow regardless of DB and syscall optimisations. I'm kinda getting the vibe of over-optimisation: if you are writing in as high level language as python, then 100x optimization of nanosecond-long call will not yield any noticeable overall improvement of execution speed. If you need to optimize your code down to the function calls - ditch the python and write in C, you'll achieve much greater speedup that way.

Comment: No, you'll still need the dirwalk +one stat() system call per file. To benchmark your program, compare it to  `find . -ls >/dev/null`, which essentialy does the same, in terms of syscalls.  I expect the python overhead will not be more than ~10% on top of this.

Comment: It's possible that [statx](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) with just the STATX_MTIME flag (and no other flags) will be slightly more efficient than `stat`, but it would need to be benchmarked.

Answer (score -1):

Kinda hard to find sources claiming non-existence of something;)

[Linux man page for fstat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) doesn't link to anything about bulk stat requests, so I assume it's nonexistent.

Besides, if you're accepting large performance penalties of using python, you shouldn't care about optimising one of the most optimised things in the OS. Python is inherently slow due to its dynamic high-level nature, so more effective optimisations include:

- using faster algorithms in python
- splitting the computational work via [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) and network work via [threads](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html)/[coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio.html)
- running your code under [pypy](http://pypy.org) (which offers jit compilation)
- rewriting parts of your program in [cython](http://cython.org) (statically typed python that is compiled into C)
- rewriting parts of your program in C and connecting them back to python via [extentions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/extending.html)
- just writing your program in C/C++/go/rust/any other compiled language

Quick rule of thumb: until your program doesn't consume 100% of all cores of CPU (or one core of your CPU for inherently unparallelizable tasks) you shouldn't consider optimising anything except your current code at the algorithm, networking and concurrency levels.

Part of a language design is speed of programming vs speed of execution balance. Achieving faster execution speed requires more input from a programmer and slows down development. If your program's slowest place is 10000 syscalls - then you should definitely be writing it in C, but I'm sure that you can find plenty of other things in your program to optimise.

I recommend using profiler (for example built in [profile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html)) to see the real hotspots in your code.